# When a processor has a given frequency, what is the order of magnitude of the typical transition frequency of the internal transistors that make it?

Tags: transistors, microprocessor

The transition frequency (or cut-off frequency) of a transistor represents the cut off frequency, so that above it, the behaviour is not normal (the impedance diverges).

A processor is made of a huge number of transistors. When a processor is working at a given frequency, let's say for example 3 GHz, what is the *typical* transition frequency of the transistors that make this processor. Is it the same ? 10 times higher ? 100 times ?

This corresponds to the generic question :
When a computer processor has a given frequency, what is the order of magnitude of the typical transition frequency of the internal transistors that make it ?

Comment: Any answer for your question is complex. There is no one good "rule of thumb" that can be comprehensive and understandable. When bleeding edge silicon fabrication is used too many other issues combine and just making all of the transistor "fast" is not a good enough solution. On chip thermal management is now an essential part of all ASIC designs when operating at the maximum achievable clock speeds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a complete answer:

Of the order of 10x (on the high side) I think, for a high performance CPU; more for a less optimised one.

It's more often expressed as the number of primitive (NAND/NOR) gate delays in a clock cycle, which is computable from the logic design, and I recall reading in the Dec Alpha/Pentium Pro era that the target for some CPU design was 14 gate delays in a clock period : that is, every logic path between registers had to be <= 14 gates (considered as 2 input NAND gates).

This was unusually tight, aiming at a fast clocked CPU for its day. May have been the Pentium-4 which had an unusually long pipeline (introducing extra pipeline registers to reduce the length of logic chains in each pipeline stage).

Found a [paper from 2002](http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~dbrooks/cs246/deep-pipes.pdf) discussing this tradeoff; it describes pipeline stages reducing from 84 gate delays to 12 at one point, and discusses the DEC Alpha 21264 in some depth.

The delay in a gate is naturally related to the Ft of its transistors; I don't know the relationship offhand.

Put these two factors together and you will have your answer.

Comment: Often defined as "FO4" gate delay (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FO4), as shown in the paper.